# How do I pass down a custom string from typescript, in the formGroup, and read the value of it in *ngFor inside template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Consider the following formArray excerpt inside the template:

```
<div class="p-col-12 controls-div" formArrayName="fields">
    <div
        class="p-grid"
        *ngFor="let item of getFieldControls(); let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
        style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="p-col-8">
            <!-- if string is Text -->
            <input
                *ngIf="string == 'Text'"
                type="text"
                pInputText
                formControlName="control">
            <!-- if string is number -->
            <input
                *ngIf="string == 'Number'"
                type="text"
                pInputText
                formControlName="control">
             <!-- if string is Yes/No -->
             <p-toggleButton
                *ngIf="string == 'Yes/No'" 
                onLabel="Yes" 
                offLabel="No" 
                formControlName="control"></p-toggleButton>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col-2">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-danger"
            (click)="onDeleteField(i)">X</button>
        </div>
    </div>                        
</div>
```

I want to pass down a string from my getFieldControls() method and bind to the control, in the *ngFor loop, to the correct "type of control" (element). My problem is I tried a 100 different ways to pass this string. I tried adding a data-type attribute like so:

```
(<FormArray>this.itemForm.get('fields')).push(
        new FormGroup({
          'control': new FormControl(
            {data-type: 'number', value:variable.name, disabled:true}, [Validators.required])
        })
      );
```

I then wanted to read it, in template, like so:

```
*ngIf="item[0].control.data-type == 'text'"
```

but the compiler complained. It seems that I can only pass down value and disabled. Later on I tried setting a value to the formgroup, also no luck. If I can pass a string I would know which control to load into the DOM in the template. I also tried to add the element directly, dynamically, from typescript like so:

```
<div [innerHTML]="elementToAdd"></div>
```

and in typescript

```
if (this.type == 'number') {
    elementToAdd += '<input type="number" ...>';
}
```

When I did this, every time a add a control the I added like 4 or 8 controls. At the end of the day I would get a, lets say 'dropdown', value (string) in the template and *ngIf only the dropdown and then bind to it.

I use an array to find, based on an id, which type of control to load. My method to push a new control looks like so:

```
onAddField(id: string) {
    let variable = this.variables.find(i => i.id === id);
    
    if (variable?.control == 'Text') {
      //add an Input
      (<FormArray>this.itemForm.get('fields')).push(
        new FormGroup({
          'control': new FormControl(
            {value:variable.name, disabled:true}, Validators.required)
        })
      );
    }
    if (variable?.control == 'Number') {
      //add an Input
      (<FormArray>this.itemForm.get('fields')).push(
        new FormGroup({
          'control': new FormControl(
            {value:variable.name, disabled:true}, Validators.required)
        })
      );
    }
    //somewhere in the formgroup or formcontrol I want to pass a string so that I can know which form control to load, using *ngIf,in the template.
  }
```

I init my form like so:

```
this.itemForm = new FormGroup({
  fields: new FormArray([])
});
```

And to get the controls, here is my method:

```
getFieldControls() {
  let controls = (this.itemForm.get('fields') as FormArray).controls;
  return controls;
}
```

Comment: Does pushing any input (without knowing its type) is working for you?

Comment: I know the type of control (text or number or dropdown, etc.) in typescript but how do I signal template which on to load into dom (*ngIf)? I need, in template, to say if ("something" == 'text') make the input of type="text" load. "something" is my how to do this question.

Comment: @ShayD, how do I cast down from item to the attributes values of the control? Example, *ngIf="item[0].control.data-type == 'text'"?

Comment: Who is your item? What its structure?

Comment: if I take out the data-type attribute then I can push correctly but how can I know in the template which control I want to load into DOM? I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have in the template array of items (returned from getFieldControls()) and you want to check for each item what type of control it is. But you didn't posted in your question the interface of 'item' so I cant tell how to figure its type.

Comment: @ShayD, I added the interface of item now. Would you help me further...

Comment: @ShayD, How do I check for each item what type of control it is from within the template using *ngIf?

Comment: If your item is really Variable type then `item.control == 'Number'`. but I have a feeling that your method `getFieldControls()` is not returning `Variable[]`. can you show more of your form building code and the method return type?

Comment: getFieldControls() {
    let controls = (this.itemForm.get('fields') as FormArray).controls;
    return controls;
  }

Comment: @ShayD, I was wrong about the item type. It's not Variable. It's just a form control that I want to bind to template form control. What I'm asking is how can I send a string from typescript where I add a new form control into the form group which gets pushed into the formarray and read that string in template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it that way.

```
<div class="p-col-12 controls-div" formArrayName="fields">
    <div
        class="p-grid"
        *ngFor="let item of getFieldControls(); let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
        style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <div class="p-col-8">
            <!-- if string is Text -->
            <input
                *ngIf="typeList[index] == 'Text'"
                type="text"
                pInputText
                formControlName="control">
            <!-- if string is number -->
            <input
                *ngIf="typeList[index] == 'Number'"
                type="text"
                pInputText
                formControlName="control">
             <!-- if string is Yes/No -->
             <p-toggleButton
                *ngIf="typeList[index] == 'Yes/No'" 
                onLabel="Yes" 
                offLabel="No" 
                formControlName="control"></p-toggleButton>
        </div>
        <div class="p-col-2">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-danger"
            (click)="onDeleteField(i)">X</button>
        </div>
    </div>                        
</div>
```

and in `onAddField()` you can do it as. because I think `variable` is somewhat relevant here.

```
typeList: stringp[] = [];
onAddField(id: string) {
    let variable = this.variables.find(i => i.id === id);
    this.typeList.push(variable?.control)
    
    if (variable?.control == 'Text') {
      //add an Input
      (<FormArray>this.itemForm.get('fields')).push(
        new FormGroup({
          'control': new FormControl(
            {value:variable.name, disabled:true}, Validators.required)
        })
      );
    }
    if (variable?.control == 'Number') {
      //add an Input
      (<FormArray>this.itemForm.get('fields')).push(
        new FormGroup({
          'control': new FormControl(
            {value:variable.name, disabled:true}, Validators.required)
        })
      );
    }
    //somewhere in the formgroup or formcontrol I want to pass a string so that I can know which form control to load, using *ngIf,in the template.
  }
```

Comment: Can you read the updates. I no longer use data-type attribute. Also, [type]="item[0].data-type" doesn't work. I'm trying to choose between different html elements (dropdown, input, radio, select, etc) in .ts and *ngIf the correct one in template. This I want to do by passing down a string from typescript and read it in template. Someone said pass down a second param in formgroup/formcontrol but I'm struggling. Based on what I said do you have ANY resolution for me? Thanks already

Comment: try to find out, are you really getting value in `item[0].data-type` or   `item[0].get('data-type').value` by using any debbuging method.

Comment: I can't pass data-type as n third key value pair in form control argument. I can only pass two attributes namely value and disabled. Let me try your siggestions though...

Comment: I think you think I only want to set type property of control. I do not. I want to pass a string from my typescript (in formgroup/formcontrol) and read it in template. If the string is, for instance, 'number' then I want  to add, using *ngIf, a input with type number. If the string is 'select' I want to add, again using *ngIf, a select element. The same with dropdown, textarea, etc. I tried to dynamically add the html element straight from typescript but I then ended up with more controls (elems) than I 'm adding. You should understand by now what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: I got a bit of understanding, I think some necessary code is still missing, from where you are invoking the `onAddField` function. and where you updating or creating `variables` variable.

Comment: variables is irrelevant. Just how can I send down a string and be able to read in ngFor. Kindly reread my question. I refactored it. Maybe it's simpler now. Thanks for sticking by still

Comment: I just updated the answer checkout if it is solving your problem.

Comment: You are awesome :)